# @react-google-maps/api with custom overlay unclickable

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps-api

I am building a react google map to render property listings and everything is visually fine

My `CustomOverlay` component is made to replace default markers and renders accordingly, but doesn't enable clicking on the div even though the function assigned to `div.onclick` is visible against the each div.

Placing a console.log inside of the `div.onclick` never gets fired in console.

Any help appreciated in how I can make this custom overlay clickable just like a marker (or an alternative method is welcomed, too, but I do intend to conditionally change styling based on marker values).

Thanks.

### CustomOverlay.js

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useGoogleMap } from '@react-google-maps/api';

const CustomOverlay = ({ marker, onMarkerClick }) => {
  const map = useGoogleMap();
  const overlayView = useRef(null);
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    const overlay = new window.google.maps.OverlayView();

    overlay.onAdd = function () {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const priceRounded = (marker.price / 1000000).toFixed(1);

      div.style.position = 'absolute';
      div.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
      div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      div.style.zIndex = '1';

      div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="price-label">£${priceRounded}m</div>
        <div class="fee-label">${marker.fee_offered}%</div>
      `;
  
      const onClickFunction = () => {
        onMarkerClick(marker);
      };

      div.onclick = onClickFunction;

      divRef.current = div;
      overlay.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
    };

    overlay.draw = function () {
      const div = divRef.current;
      const point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(marker.position);
      if (point) {
        div.style.left = point.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = point.y + 'px';
      }
    };

    overlay.onRemove = function () {
      if (divRef.current) {
        this.getPanes().overlayLayer.removeChild(divRef.current);
      }
    };

    overlay.setMap(map);
    overlayView.current = overlay;

    return () => {
      overlayView.current.setMap(null);
    };
  }, [map]);

  return null;
};

export default CustomOverlay;
```

### Map.js

```
  import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
} from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, InfoWindow } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { containerStyle, mapOptions } from './MapConfig';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getAccessToken } from '../../../../auth';
import './MapStyling/customoverlay.css';
import CustomOverlay from './MapComponents/CustomOverlay';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
});

api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (token) {
      config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => Promise.reject(error),
);

const Map = () => {
  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: 'google-map-script',
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY,
  });

  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);
  const [infoWindowVisible, setInfoWindowVisible] = useState(false);
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  const handleMarkerClick = useCallback(
    (marker) => {
      setInfoWindowVisible(false);
      setSelectedMarker(marker);
      setInfoWindowVisible(true);
    },
    [setSelectedMarker, setInfoWindowVisible],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const token = getAccessToken();
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + 'listing/',
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Accept: 'application/json',
            },
          },
        );

        const markers = response.data.map((listing) => {
          let { lat, lng } = listing;
          let RestOfListing = { ...listing };
          delete RestOfListing.lat;
          delete RestOfListing.lng;

          return {
            position: {
              lat,
              lng,
            },
            ...RestOfListing,
          };
        });
        setMarkers(markers);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        setMarkers([]);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const memoizedMarkers = useMemo(() => {
    return markers.map((marker) => (
      <CustomOverlay
        key={marker.id}
        marker={marker}
        onMarkerClick={() => handleMarkerClick(marker)}
      />
    ));
  }, [markers]);

  return isLoaded ? (
    <GoogleMap
      mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
      options={mapOptions}
      ref={mapRef}
      onClick={() => {
        setInfoWindowVisible(false);
        setSelectedMarker(null);
      }}
    >
      {memoizedMarkers}
      {infoWindowVisible && selectedMarker && (
        <InfoWindow
          position={selectedMarker.position}
          onCloseClick={() => {
            setInfoWindowVisible(false);
            setSelectedMarker(null);
          }}
        >
          <div>
            <h4>Marker ID: {selectedMarker.id}</h4>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  ) : null;
};

export default Map;
```

### customoverlay.css

```
.custom-marker {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-25%, 0%);
}


.price-label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(22, 0, 87, 0.8);
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.fee-label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d62828;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  translate: -125%;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```